# Styling Raster with QGIS for publishing in Geoserver

Tags: raster, geoserver

I have a raster layer with five different landcover types denoting with 1,2,3,4 and 5. in Qgis it looks as follows:

[image]

When I tried to upload this layer to geoserver using OpenGeo explorer tools, and visualize it in geoexplorer, the legend changed and showed some unexpectred 'x' there. Why is it so ? How can I retain the same legend style that I made in Qgis  in geoserver? here is the picture from geoexplorer:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can go to geoserver administration page, go to Style memu and then edit that sld style.  There should be tags like `<name>` and you can change it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain in depth how to change name tags? Because I have the x between my intervals and I am looking for something more professional.